# Robotframework Listener throws "Cannot access execution context" error

Tags: robotframework

In order to support an alternative logging format I've started the development of a [custom Robotframework Listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface). Using the examples in the guide I've been able to replicate the simple [PythonListner example](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-examples). This example can be succesfully run using:

```
python.exe -m robot.run --listener C:\temp\tiny.py -s Test02.Test C:\temp\Test02
```

The by the listener class generated file contains the different events that have occurred and the functionality is working as it should.

When adding the following line to the `__init__` method of the class:

```
BuiltIn().get_variable_value('${SUITE SOURCE}')
```

The following response is received:

```
 failed: Creating instance failed: RobotNotRunningError: Cannot access execution context
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\tiny.py", line 9, in __init__
    print  repr(BuiltIn().get_variables())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries\BuiltIn.py", line 940, in get_variables
    return utils.NormalizedDict(self._variables.current, ignore='_')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries\BuiltIn.py", line 2669, in _variables
    return self._namespace.variables
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries\BuiltIn.py", line 2661, in _namespace
    return self._context.namespace
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries\BuiltIn.py", line 2656, in _context
    raise RobotNotRunningError('Cannot access execution context')
==============================================================================
Test02
==============================================================================
Test02.Test
==============================================================================
Process Data File                                                     | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test02.Test                                                           | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Test02                                                                | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\temp\output.xml
Log:     C:\temp\log.html
Report:  C:\temp\report.html
```

The test passes but the file is not generated. This result has been replicated on Python 2.7 and Robotframework 3.0 and 2.8.5. It is odd and I need some help to further analyse or (ideally) solve this problem.

Since the Python class is called by Robotframework I'm unsure how to continue debugging this, so feel free to make suggestions there as well. In any case I'm stuck and could use your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to reference `BuiltIn()` before the test starts. That is what is meant by the error `Cannot access execution context`: the test hasn't started so there is no execution context. Simply put, you cannot access methods of the `BuiltIn` library before the test runs.

You will have to wait to call that statement until after the test has started running.

For example:

```
class listener:
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def start_suite(self, name, attrs):
        self.suite_source = BuiltIn().get_variable_value('${SUITE SOURCE}')
```

However, if all you need is the source of the current suite, that information is available in the listener method `start_suite`.

For example:

```
class MyListener:
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def start_suite(self, name, attrs):
        self.suite_source = attrs["source"]
```

Comment: This behaviour I had noticed as well and it makes sense for test specific variables. However, for the Global Variables (like OUTPUT_DIR), which are set at the start of Robotframework itself I'd expect that these would be accessible during the initialisation of the listener. In this case the SUITE_SOURCE might not have been the right example to use. Any thoughts?

Comment: @A.Kootstra: I agree some of that information ought to be made available when the listener is initialized.

Comment: so how to test the code snippet containing the statement like BuiltIn().get_variable_value('${SUITE SOURCE}') without a context?

Comment: @stefanzweig: You can't.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you very much. so what is the strategy to implement a keyword that need to know the robot variables?

Comment: @stefanzweig: I don't understand the question. The strategy is to use `BuiltIn().get_variable_value(...)`.  Why do you need to get the variables before the test is running?

Comment: what I meant is after a keyword is implemented in python it should be tested. If some unit test is needed and the unit test is totally in python, it is not possible to access the robot context, say, all the unit tests are triggered by jenkins. how to do this kind of pure programming language unit testing? thank you. @BryanOakley

Comment: @stefanzweig: you'll have to mock it out somehow if you're testing keywords without using robot, or use robot to run your keyword unit tests.