# Is it possible to get a python interactive console with Robot environment initialised?

Tags: python, console, robotframework

I need to debug a library that uses Robot (mostly BuiltIn). Trying to import it from Python console returns an exception:

> File "[path]/robot/libraries/BuiltIn.py", line 66, in _get_context
>       raise RobotNotRunningError('Cannot access execution context')

I found robotframework-debuglibrary but it seems to create a Robot shell, not a Python one. Is there an effective solution to that problem?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate Question Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266784/robotframework-listener-throws-cannot-access-execution-context-error) if it works for you.

Comment: It is not duplicate or relevant, that question is about using the robot libraries inside of a test, not an interactive console.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to import Robot Framework into python environment? Try checking the versions compatibility of Robot Framework you have and the version of Python you are using.
Robot Framework is supported on Python (both Python 2 and Python 3), Jython (JVM) and IronPython (.NET) and PyPy. The interpreter you want to use should be installed before installing the framework itself.

Comment: I have a full robot testing environment set up. I want to run one python library that uses robot in an interactive console.

Comment: You might want to read these preconditions: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#preconditions and figure out what best suits your OS and Python Environment.

Comment: _I already have Robot set up._ That instruction covers setup and running tests, not interactive shell (if possible).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I'm not sure if you could do this or not but I'm sure you could posibbly find much help here: https://robotframework-slack-invite.herokuapp.com/